# How can I split the last instance of a character in a C# string?

Tags: c#, arrays, string

I have a string that looks like this

```
/root/test/test2/tesstset-werew-1
```

And I want to parse the word after the last `/`. So in this example, I want to grab the word `tesstset-werew-1`. **What is the best way of doing this in C#?** Should I split the string into an array or is there some built in function for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The Split() method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a.aspx)

```
string mystring = "/root/test/test2/tesstset-werew-1";

var mysplitstring = mystring.split("/");

string lastword = mysplitstring[mysplitstring.length - 1];
```

Answer (score 3):

If this is a path, which seems to be the case in your example you can use [`Path.GetFileName()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename.aspx):

```
string fileName = Path.GetFileName("/root/test/test2/tesstset-werew-1");
```

Answer (score 2):

```
yourString.Substring(yourString.LastIndexOf('/') + 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Splitting into an array is probably the easiest way to do it. The other would be `regex`

something like this would work:

```
string[] segments = yourString.Split('/');
try
{
  lastSegment = segments[segments.length - 1];
}
catch (IndexOutOfRangeException)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Your original string does not have slashes");
}
```

You would want to put a check that segments[] has elements before the second statement.

Answer (score 0):

You can run the for loop in reverse order till the `/` sign.